# Scanner doesnt take the input that i give

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I tried everything, after the press `1` to run or press `2` to give him the cannabis it goes to `System.out.println("You own: ...!");`

## questions

Why does my program not take the input that I give it?

Why does it do this?

What did I do wrong?

Everything I used I believe is correct, please help

## code

```
    while (canabisOwn > 0) {

        System.out.println("You own: " + canabisOwn + " canabis!");
        System.out.println("You have " + health + " health");
        System.out.println("You can run with: " + mySpeed + " km/hr");
        System.out.println("\n \t What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("\t 1. Sell");
        System.out.println("\t 2. Find dealer");
        System.out.println("\t 3. Smoke");

        String input = in.nextLine();

        if (input.equals("1")) {

            if (peopleC > CopC) {

                canabisOwn -= peopleCBC;

                System.out.println("You found someone and you sold " + peopleCBC + " canabis");

            } else if (CopC > peopleC) {

                print("A cop found you. Risk and run or give him the canabis?");
                print("Press 1 to run ");
                print("Press 2 to give him the canabis");

                input = in.nextLine();

                if (input.equals("1")) {
                    if (CopSpeed > mySpeed) {
                        health -= 30;

                        print("The cop catched you");
                        print("You dont have any canabis,you have to find some");
                    }
                }

                else if (input.equals("2")) {
                    canabisOwn -= canabisOwn;
                    print("You dont have any canabis");
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

when I use print store's `System.out.println(String s)` and blabla...

Comment: You need to make the problem a bit more clear. Please mark the steps you're trying along with input provided and output you're getting and then what is expected.

Comment: ...btw there are many variables defined out of scope of the code that you've shared. You must share details(values) in reference to them as well.

Comment: also make sure the code you posted is at least complete, some close braces `}` are missing, plz post a complete code

Comment: What is the initial value of canibisown

Comment: And initial value of other variables?

Answer (score 1):

Primarily, use -

```
System.out.println("The cop catched you");
```

instead

```
print("The cop catched you");
```

(in all such occurrences) unless you have your own definition of the method `print(String str)` in the code.